# How can i extract the year from year column of data type datetime(ns)?

Tags: python, datetime

```
        1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013
27804   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013
27805   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013
27806   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013
27807   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013
27808   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014
```

At the right most you can see that **2013** and **2014** I want only those in my year column.

Comment: It looks like the year is 1970 and not 2013.

Comment: how is the datetime column derived? if the rightmost 4 digits represent the year, something is going wrong. the input seems to be year, not seconds since the epoch.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. As @MrFuppes already noted, there seems to be an error in the creation of the data. To understand that more context is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this (this time we work with datetime and extract the year part)

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17),
                    'value': 12}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 17),
                                   'value': 33}])

print(df)
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d: d.year)
print(df)
```

output

```
        date  value
0 2020-05-17     12
1 2012-05-17     33
   date  value
0  2020     12
1  2012     33
```

Comment: It wont help because the data type is in datetime format and it cannot be sliced.. :/

Comment: @wasirehman see the updated answer - this time working with datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data to string and select the last 4 digits.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013'], ['1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014']],columns = ['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str).str[-4:]
df

    date
---------
0   2013
1   2014
```